# Flask throwing 500 internal server error

Tags: python, flask, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

This is what my routes.py looks like. Basically its a crawler which crawls all youtube video links within a page. This code works fine standalone (not in flask). However, when i try to make it work via flask, it throws 500 internal server error. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import requests
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    url="https://www.youtube.com/user/EminemVEVO/videos"
    source_code=requests.get(url)
    text_source_code=source_code.text
    final_code=BeautifulSoup(text_source_code)
    video_url=final_code.findAll('a',{'class':'yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link  spf-link  yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2'})

    for i in video_url:
        if "/watch?v=" in i.get('href'):
            j= i.get('href')
            j=j.replace("/watch?v=","")
            print "http://youtube.com"+j

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Stack trace is below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1478, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1566, in make_response
    raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

Comment: Can you please add stack trace? Also maybe re-format the code (it's not too bad though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main()` method, routed to `'/'`, does not return any values. You print youtube URLs to the console, but nothing is being sent back to the client. Flask doesn't like that, and most likely this is not what you intended.

Return the list of URLs to the user:

```
@app.route("/")
def main():
    ...

    data_to_return = []
    for i in video_url:
        if "/watch?v=" in i.get('href'):
            j= i.get('href')
            j=j.replace("/watch?v=","")
            data_to_return.append("http://youtube.com"+j)
    return '\n'.join(data_to_return)
```